# How we can add a strongly typed PowerShell to automcomplete the properties (intellisense)?

Tags: powershell

I am writing a long [Microsoft 365 Patterns & Practices](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/microsoft-365-patterns-and-practices-pnp-november-2020-update/) PowerShell script, so is there a tool that can allow us to get the properties of our variables, something as follows (I got this picture from the web which describe what I am looking for):

[image]

Comment: `$list | get-member` unless you want to add more information to your question so we know what you're actually asking.

Comment: @shadow2020 i am asking in general, how visual studio autocomplete the code for us, is there available tool for powershell espically PnP?

Comment: @shadow2020 simialr to how our c# code works inside visual studio, and as shown in the picture i found on the net.. so seems there are such a tool for powershell as well?

Comment: @shadow2020 i am search for intellisense for powershell code

Comment: seems like you're asking how to develop a [`class`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.2). autocompletion works fine on them.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon i am looking for a tool which provide  intellisense for powershell code .. seems u did not get my question

Comment: Well you're showing PowerShell ISE intellisense over an instance of an object, in VS Code you can get something similar with the PowerShell Extension (preferable preview). Other than that, and as you may see by the upvotes in the first comment your question doesnt make much sense :)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon the picture i got it from the web ,, just to describe what i am looking for

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon not sure if you are understanding what i am asking :)

Comment: Have you tried vscode:extension/ms-vscode.PowerShell?

Comment: Intellisence works in PowerShell via `Ctrl + SPACE`. Although, I am not sure what you're asking for. If you're not getting any intellisence from an instance of an object, that means it's information-type has been stripped, or it just didn't have none to begin with.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala which tool or console i need to use? Windows power Shell?

Comment: @MarkReed will try it for sure, but then i will be writing my power-shell scripts inside visual studio instead of windows power shell ? am i correct ?

Comment: @MarkReed i installed the vscode:extension/ms-vscode.PowerShell but i did not get any project template for powershell.. any advie?

Comment: @JohnJohn Open your start menu, type "Run" and hit enter. In the Runbox type, "Powershell_ISE". In the window which pops up, type, "string" in double quotes followed by a "." dot. You will see intelliisence. Is this what your question is about? How to view the intellisence? Everybody commenting here in the comments that your question makes no sense. That is supposed to be your que to edit your question until it does make sense.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75378980/edit). Thanks in advance.

Comment: *[Get-PnPList](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPList.html)*